# O Google não reconhece uma Label ligado ao input

Tags: google

Nas regras de acessebilidade do google se diz que todo input tem que ter um label. Ok!

Acontece que estou botando o atributo `for` igual ao `id` do input, porém o Google ainda acusa no relatório do Lighthouse que o input não tem nenhum label associado.

Segue um exemplo que o Google não reconhece:

```html
<div class="boxCampoPu">
  <input id="puNome" type="text" class="puNome" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
  <label for="puNome"> Insira seu nome</label>
</div>
```

Alguém sabe explicar o pq que isso ocorre?

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente não é deste item.

Rodei o seu código no lighthouse local e não foi possível reproduzir.

Segue o html que utilizei:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="boxCampoPu">
      <input id="puNome" type="text" class="puNome" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
      <label for="puNome"> Insira seu nome</label>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

A pontuação para este código no quesito acessibilidade é 100%:

Segue o print:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Informações do chrome:

Versão 88.0.4324.190 (Versão oficial) 64 bits

Comment: Acabei de fazer isso. Mesmo resultado.

Comment: Como assim não é desse item? Você está falando que o id não corresponde ao for? Ficou meio confuso.

Comment: Sim. Eu postei o código e o resultado. O que está confuso? Não foi possível reproduzir o seu problema. O que não ficou claro? Eu postei o código html e o resultado.